# QueryTable: How to get 'Reading Data' value in VBA

Tags: database, vba, excel

I am building a VBA application and have a very slow connection to a SQL database. To inform the user about the progress I want to show a progress percentage in the statusbar.

So far I have noticed that Excel itself display the amount of read data rows in the status bar.  See [image: Excel's reading data].

**My question is: How do I retrieve that value to display my own progress bar?**

Apparently, i can set the query into the background and monitor the refreshing status, but where do I get the data from:

```
Set listObj = destinationSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
"OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
"Network Library=DBMSSOCN;" & _
"Persist Security Info=False;" & _
"User ID=" & sqlUser & _
";Password=" & sqlPassword & _
";Data Source=" & sqlServerName & _
";Initial Catalog=" & sqlDatabaseName), _
Destination:=destinationRange)   

With listObj.QueryTable
    'Some other code here
     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
     While .Refreshing
         Application.StatusBar = "What now?" 'How to get the Reading Data value
     Wend
End With
```

Comment: Where did you get the info that you can monitor the refreshing status?  The way to do this would be to create a class module, have a QueryTable object declared in it using the WithEvents keyword and then catch the appropriate event, which would then trigger your progressbar update.  But I had a quick look and, in Excel 2010 at least, the only two events for a QueryTable object are BeforeRefresh and AfterRefresh, which don't sound like they'll be of much use to you.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this, despite there is no such built-in vba feature, you would have to know total rows count to be read before you start refreshing. Do you know it? If not, how would you calculate progress?

Comment: @avb: I am able to find out the total number of rows, by issuing e.g. a "Select COUNT(*)" query. Nevertheless, I will still need to check how much data is already loaded.